# INNER JOIN with Condition - Mysql

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm trying to make an inner join if a condition is true but it does not work, I've tried these 2 ways:

```
IF chat.tipo = 'vitima' THEN
   INNER JOIN vitima ON vitima.id_vit = chat.id_tipo

ELSE
   INNER JOIN terceiro ON terceiro.id_ter = chat.id_tipo
```

or

```
IF(chat.tipo = 'vitima', 
        INNER JOIN vitima ON vitima.id_vit = chat.id_tipo,
        INNER JOIN terceiro ON terceiro.id_ter = chat.id_tipo)
```

But both give error, what I want is if the type equals "vitima" it does the inner noin in one table, otherwise in the other.

Full query:

```
SELECT ocorrencia.id_oco, 
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.id_oco ORDER BY c.id_oco DESC) FROM ocorrencia as c WHERE c.id_sup_oco = ocorrencia.id_sup_oco) as grouped_ids, 
        ocorrencia.id_sup_oco, 
        chat.id_tipo,
        suporte_oco.data_sup,
        suporte_oco.placa_sup,
        suporte_oco.sinistro_sup,
        suporte_oco.prefixo_sup,
        ocorrencia.id_emp_oco,
        IF(chat.tipo = 'vitima', vitima.nome_vit, terceiro.nome_ter) as nome,
        chat.tipo

        FROM chat 
        INNER JOIN ocorrencia ON ocorrencia.id_oco = chat.id_oco_cha 
        INNER JOIN suporte_oco ON suporte_oco.id_sup = ocorrencia.id_sup_oco

        IF chat.tipo = 'vitima'
            INNER JOIN vitima ON vitima.id_vit = chat.id_tipo
        ELSE
            INNER JOIN terceiro ON terceiro.id_ter = chat.id_tipo

        WHERE chat.id_user = '20' OR chat.id_user_req = '20' GROUP BY (chat.id_oco_cha) ORDER BY chat.data DESC
```

Comment: Can I ask, what's your purpose of the conditional JOIN?  Since you aren't actually selecting anything from those tables, are you just trying to make sure that a corresponding record exists?

Comment: @billynoah There where I select the fields I also made a "if", do not know if it will work kkkkk, I want to get the name, see: `IF(chat.tipo = 'vitima', vitima.nome_vit, terceiro.nome_ter) as nome`

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.  In that case, I think a left join as in my answer might work best, since you might need a column from either table.  Another option would be create a subquery - it's hard to give an exact solution without the schema and sample data but I think you're close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exact, but I think this would come really close to what you're trying to do:

```
LEFT JOIN vitima ON vitima.id_vit = chat.id_tipo AND chat.tipo = 'vitima'
LEFT JOIN terceiro ON terceiro.id_ter = chat.id_tipo AND chat.tipo != 'vitima'
...
WHERE (chat.tipo = 'vitima' AND vitima.id_vit IS NOT NULL)
    OR (chat.tipo != 'vitima' AND terceiro.id_ter IS NOT NULL)
```

The `LEFT JOIN` conditions enforce your rules and the `WHERE` condition simulates and `INNER JOIN` since it requires those records to exist.

With the complete query you posted it would look like this:

```
SELECT ocorrencia.id_oco, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.id_oco ORDER BY c.id_oco DESC) FROM ocorrencia as c WHERE c.id_sup_oco = ocorrencia.id_sup_oco) as grouped_ids, 
    ocorrencia.id_sup_oco, 
    chat.id_tipo,
    suporte_oco.data_sup,
    suporte_oco.placa_sup,
    suporte_oco.sinistro_sup,
    suporte_oco.prefixo_sup,
    ocorrencia.id_emp_oco,
    IF(chat.tipo = 'vitima', vitima.nome_vit, terceiro.nome_ter) as nome,
    chat.tipo

FROM chat 
    INNER JOIN ocorrencia ON ocorrencia.id_oco = chat.id_oco_cha 
    INNER JOIN suporte_oco ON suporte_oco.id_sup = ocorrencia.id_sup_oco
    LEFT JOIN vitima ON vitima.id_vit = chat.id_tipo AND chat.tipo = 'vitima'
    LEFT JOIN terceiro ON terceiro.id_ter = chat.id_tipo AND chat.tipo != 'vitima'

WHERE chat.id_user = '20' OR chat.id_user_req = '20'
    AND (
        (chat.tipo = 'vitima' AND vitima.id_vit IS NOT NULL)
        OR (chat.tipo != 'vitima' AND terceiro.id_ter IS NOT NULL)
    )
GROUP BY (chat.id_oco_cha) ORDER BY chat.data DESC
```

Comment: "You have a syntax error in your SQL 'LEFT JOIN vitima ON vitima.id_vit = chat.id_tipo AND chat.tipo = 'vitima'
    L' at line 17"

Comment: thanks, there was a stray comma there. It's fixed now.

Comment: It worked :), just take the first `INNER JOIN` there on table `vitima`

Comment: oh yeah, i see that one was doubled. glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use conditions in `join`, probably its easier to use `union` like:

```
select * from chat inner join vitima ON 
union all
select * from chat inner join terceiro ON chat.tipo <> 'vitima' AND terceiro.id_ter = chat.id_tipo
```

another variant I can think of is:

```
select *
from chat, vitima, terceiro
where
(chat.tipo = 'vitima' AND vitima.id_vit = chat.id_tipo)
OR
(chat.tipo <> 'vitima' AND terceiro.id_ter = chat.id_tipo)
```

Comment: I'll put the complete query for you to see, I tried it here but I can not adapt

Comment: Take a look now